# Algorithm to calculate number of child per each parent from excel file

Tags: python, dataframe, algorithm, data-structures, excel-formula

I have an excel file containing 2 columns & 763 row, screenshot :
[parent-child file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFaTh.png)

Those strange strings is just a code for a mobile sites.

As a description, this file has in both columns a mobile sites names, and as you know, mobile sites forward mobile traffic to each other, so the parent site forward traffic to the child site.
Important note : The parent site could have more than one child, plus, parent site could be a child for other sites.

for example :
A parent of B, B parent of C, C parent of D. what is I need when I enter A, output : site A has three children--> they are C,B,D.

what I need as a result is adding a new column to this file having the value of : number of child sites depending on this parent site, so when I get an alarm telling me that this parent site is down, I can know how many sites affected also (using the new excel file).

The excel file is in the following link so you can get better look: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ljXiYvNWmG-x7hRi0PyVZ6ejbC4wT8FI/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=114185320765894103697&rtpof=true&sd=true

until now I wrote this :
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\jalal.hasain\Desktop')
print(df)
I will appreciate it if you have any idea to solve this problem, I need help in creating the third column values, I tried to write a python code and stored the excel in pandas df, but I couldn't get the idea of the solution.
Thanks for your cooperation, appreciated.

Comment: you cannot apply any algorithm without reading first this data from the excel fil. In the question you day "I tried to write a python code and stored the excel in pandas df"  but you haven't posted any code.

Comment: I just stored the 2 columns in a python data frame, read from the excel file is done, but I didn't know how to create the third column after that, the column must contain only the number of sites depending on this parent. Thanks for helping❤️

Comment: without seeing your code... not much we can do.

Comment: import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\jalal.hasain\Desktop')
print(df)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to build a graph.

You can combine [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) and [networkx](/questions/tagged/networkx) for this:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(pd.read_excel('CHILD--PARENT.xlsx'),
                            source='Parent', target='Child',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph)
```

Then fetch the descendants using [`nx.descendants`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.descendants.html):

```
nx.descendants(G, '064AQ')
```

Output:

```
{'070AQ', '471AQ', '040AQ'}
```

Relevant part of the graph:

[image]

A bit larger context of the graph:

[image]

Comment: I think I forgot something in my question. for example : A parent of B, B parent of C, C parent of D. what is I need when I enter A, output : site A has three children--> they are C,B,D. I will update the question now. Thanks very very very much for helping, I'm struggling in it since a while,

Comment: I realize I forgot to use a directed graph, see the update

Comment: import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
df1=pd.read_excel('CHILD--PARENT.XLSX')
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(pd.read_excel('CHILD--PARENT.XLSX'),
                            source='Parent', target='Child',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph) df1['number of child'] = len(nx.descendants(G, list(df1['Parent']))) , I wrote this to create the third column, but  it is giving error : TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' , do you have any idea how can I run this to work on the whole column of parent column not only on one value ? Thanks for helping

Comment: You can't pass a list to `nx.descendants`, you must loop to pass each element one after the other: `df1['number of child'] = [len(nx.descendants(G, n)) for n in df1['Parent']]`

Comment: I just saw your comment, and now it helped a lot, thank you.